# What is up with my Vi/Vim installation?

Tags: keyboard, vim

I had asked this question earlier but it got deleted because I happened to mention that I was using Ubuntu 9.04.

Well, I have upgraded to the second latest version,12.04 LTS, and `Vi` is still acting up.

This problem seems to only happen in `Vi` only because I have tried it with `pico` and
`gedit` all of which work as expected. In `Vi`, when I am in insert mode:

- `HOME KEY` inserts `H`
- `END KEY` inserts `F`
- `UP-ARROW KEY` inserts `B`
- `DOWN-ARROW KEY` inserts `A`
- `LEFT-ARROW KEY` inserts `C`
- `RIGHT-ARROW` inserts `D`
- `BACKSPACE` moves cursor to the left without deleting.

I find this very irritating. I need to know if this is happening to anyone else. I tried this in my friends hp laptop and it misbehaves the same way so my pc(Acer) is not the culprit here. I'm sure there's an explanation for this, *what is it and how can I fix it?*

Comment: What about vim?

Comment: Vim(built from source without gui) had the same problem in Ubuntu 9.04. I've built it right now, `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 14 2013 19:08:50)` and it still behaves the same way. @Braiam, is your installation working ok?

Comment: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep  7 2013 13:27:43)` is ok for me... where did you got that version?

Comment: From [vim's ftp site](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.4.tar.bz2). How long have you been using your Ubuntu installation? What tweaks did you make?

Comment: Did you apply any of the ubuntu's patches? With what options you compiled it?

Comment: No options, just a simple `make install` in the `src` folder. What patches are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto), Ubuntu ships with the console version of Vim.  This causes the non-standard behavior you are experiencing.  The full version of Vim should be available by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

This is one of the first things I always do when I install Ubuntu.

Comment: Can't believe it works now after installing `gvim`(not vim) using `apt`. Don't know what relation the two have, but whatever it was that caused that `apt` managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The key bindings for your vi install don't seem to be set correctly for your terminal. A quick fix is to remap them (as detailed [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29#Key_notation)):

```
:set <PageUp>=[press Ctrl-V][press PageUp]
```

where `:set <pageUp>=` is entered literally.

Comment: That was the first thing that came to mind @chronospoon. I really hate the idea of remapping the keys on a fresh install. First of all it's hackish and It feels like I'm avoiding the problem.